# Missing-\endcsname-error in a equation environment

Tags: errors

My code won't compile properly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
        \frac{d\phi}{dx} = \sqrt{\lambda}\bigg( -c_1sin\sqrt{\lambda}x
        + c_2cos\sqrt{\lambda}x)\bigg
\end{equation}
So $\frac{d\phi}{dx}(-L) = \frac{d\phi}{dx}(L)$ only if
\begin{equation}
        c_1\sqrt{\lambda}sin\sqrt{\lambda}L = 0
\end{equation}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to add `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\begin{equation}`. You can't just start in the middle like that.

Comment: Sorry,  I do have that in my code, however.

Comment: The use of `\big`-and-friends are (in this case) `\big<delim>`, not `<delim>\big`. You have `\bigg(`...`)\bigg`.

Comment: @Werner, wanna add this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `\big`-and-friend for sizing delimiters *always* take the form `\big<delim>`, regardless of whether it's the left or right delimiter:

```
... \big<ldelim> ... \big<rdelim> ...
```

In your case, you have

```
... \bigg( ... )\bigg ...
```

which is incorrect. You need

```
... \bigg( ... \bigg) ...
```

or, better said,

```
... \biggl( ... \biggr) ...
```

Using `l`eft-and-`r`ight specific sizing provides correct spacing, see the following example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \sin  \big( a + b \big) \\
  \sin \bigl( a + b \bigr)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\biggl(` and `\biggr)`.

Comment: @egreg: Yes. In this instance there was no visible difference. Are you referring to the syntactic use of `l`-and-`r` being more appropriate?

Comment: The fact that in this particular case the effect is not visible is irrelevant; try with `$\sin\big(a+b\big)$` and `$\sin\bigl(a+b\bigr)$`